# Time Capsule (3rd Gen) seems to deny internet access to clients with a static IP address

Tags: time-capsule, network

A bit of background on our: we have an Apple Time Capsule, 3rd generation, connecting to the internet through a cable modem (WAN IP is configured via DHCP).

As we can't get a signal across the house, but we do have interconnected Ethernet ports throughout the house, we've attempted to use a Buffalo (WZR-HP-G450H) router, running DD-WRT, wired to the TC and set up in bridge mode, as a repeater.

Our network was as follows:

`192.168.0.1` : Time Capsule (Gateway, DHCP Server)
`192.168.0.2` : Buffalo (Bridge / Repeater, DHCP Server turned off)
`192.168.0.3 - 192.168.0.200` : DHCP Pool (Allocated by TC)
`192.168.0.201 - 192.168.0.254` : Unallocated / Reserved

For some reason, this caused the internet to cut out every few minutes (all connections timed out, tested with `ping 8.8.8.8`). We called the ISP to come fix the problem, he (according to my mother) mumbled something about an IP conflict, and moved the TC over to the 10.0.0.x subnet, resulting in this setup.

`10.0.0.1` : Time Capsule (Gateway, DHCP Server)
`192.168.0.2` : Buffalo (Bridge / Repeater, DHCP Server turned off)
`10.0.0.3 - 10.0.0.200` : DHCP Pool (Allocated by TC)
`10.0.0.201 - 10.0.0.254` : Unallocated / Reserved

In theory, this works, although I can't access the Buffalo router's settings and I don't like that it's on a different subnet. I changed the Buffalo router back to `10.0.0.2`, and the same problems ensued. Cue my mom complaining.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see anything possibly wrong with the last setup. Additionally, while trying to set up an OpenVPN service on the Buffalo router, and after painstakingly experimenting with various port forwarding rules, I found that the Buffalo router couldn't access the internet.

I'll spare you the details, but it turns out I can't access the internet when I connect using a static IP, even if the settings are exactly the same each time. Some screenshots:

[image: DHCP-Assigned IP]
[image: Manually Assigned IP]

I'm convinced this has to with (or is the source of) all of our other network problems.

This problem is driving me nuts and I have absolutely no leads: I've called both my ISP and Apple Support and neither could give me any leads. If you have any ideas or pointers, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Do I understand correctly the modem is connected to the Time Capsule's WAN port. How does the connection from TC to Buffalo run?

Comment: That is correct. The Buffalo's WAN port is wired to one of the TC's LAN ports, but the Buffalo's WAN port is setup as a LAN port (i.e. the router has 5 LAN and 0 WAN ports). [It looks like this in the settings](http://i.imgur.com/4FF2XGB.png). I must say though, the problem is still present when I connect directly to the TC over Wi-Fi and unplug the Buffalo router completely, so I don't think that's where the problem lies.

Comment: When you set a static address, did you also manually enter a DNS server? This happens to me a lot when I'm messing with my network settings.

Comment: Ah, yes, that solves _that_ problem. Now on to the the other, bigger problem: why the hell can't I use my Buffalo router as a bridge?

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what the issue with the router is. You said is doesn't have an Internet connection?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure, just that our internet cuts out every once in a while. ISP tech says it was an IP conflict, but it doesn't look like that. FWIW, I've copied your settings exactly, putting the Buffalo WAP at 10.0.0.144, because honestly, my best guess is that it just wasn't happy being so close to the main router. I don't particularly care either; I just want it to work.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a similar setup (all in 10.0.0.x range) as I have.
- TC: connected to my modem.
- TC: Enabled DHCP server
- Linksys router (running DD-WRT): connected to the TC with a cable running from standard LAN to standard LAN port.
- Linksys router: WAN port disabled
- Linksys router: Wireless is set top bridge

Your theory sounds good. The only thing I can think of is you made a mistake with the configuration. I included some screenshots of my configurations:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's infuriating is that this is my exact setup, except that "Local DNS" is 8.8.8.8 and I have the DD-WRT router on 10.0.0.2 ([taking care to start the DHCP pool at 10.0.0.3](http://i.imgur.com/6uFI22O.png)). I've now somehow managed to put myself in a situation where I can't see the Buffalo router on my network at all, I may have to unplug it and connect to it directly. This still doesn't explain why I can't connect to the TC with a static IP though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're seeing is due to trying to use bridge mode and static addressing on the Buffalo. The solution will be to give the Buffalo a reserved IP address from the DHCP pool by associating the IP address with the Buffalo's MAC. DHCP reservations are done in Airport Utility | Network on the selected device. Then set the Buffalo to DHCP, reboot the unit and you should be good to go.

FWIW, it's not absolutely necessary to use DHCP Reservation as long as you have Buffalo's AirStation Configuration Tool installed. That said, I understand how stable IP addressing is a desirable thing.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a lot going on here, but the reason you can't get online with a static IP address even though the settings match your DHCP-provided address is (at least based on those screen shots) probably related to your DNS settings. There's no reason that a Time Capsule should deny access based on whether a client is DHCP or static. When you provide a valid DNS server manually, does it work? If not can you post screen shots like you did for the TCP/IP settings?